# Progress View stuttering when animating with loop

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to update a progress view using a property observer which is  updated in a loop with a sleep.

See this tutorial - http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/progress-view-tutorial-in-ios8-with-swift

I'm having the same problem as one of the comments.

The animation is stuttering. It jumps from 0 to 64% and then 100%.

Any idea how I can create a smoother animation?

[image: stuttering progress bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing sleep(1) to sleep(arc4random_uniform(10)). Check out this example from Apple - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Listings/Swift_UICatalog_ProgressViewController_swift.html

Hope this helps.